# rust combine similar values in a sequence

Tags: rust

In rust, given some sequence (an array, a vector, etc.), what is a good way to combine all same values and return a sequence with unique values?

For a specific example, given some array `[1, 2, 2, 3, 2]`, modify the returned array (or create a new array or vector) so that each `u32` value is only contained once, i.e. it becomes `[1, 2, 3]`.
Later, I want to iterate over the result.

In this case, "*good way*" means not too complicated, grokkable. The solution could use `std::collections`.

Comment: I don't know if "_sequence_" is good rust phrasing. I borrowed that phrase from Python.

Comment: Do you need to retain the order of the original sequence? If not, have you considered using a [HashSet](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html)?

Comment: "_Do you need to retain the order of the original sequence?_" Yes.

Answer (score 3):

Simple: dedup! As the [rust doc for `Vec::dedup`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.dedup) says:

> Removes consecutive repeated elements in the vector according to the PartialEq trait implementation.
>
> If the vector is sorted, this removes all duplicates.
>
> ```
> let mut vec = vec![1, 2, 2, 3, 2];
>
> vec.dedup();
>
> assert_eq!(vec, [1, 2, 3, 2]);
> ```

And as the doc says, if it's sorted, all duplicates are removed.  See also [`Vec::sort`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.sort).

Comment: Note to @JamesThomasMoon - The doc for `sort` explicitly says it's stable, so your order is preserved with the method from the doc I cite above.  And note to @Brian - Thanks for the formatting cleanup via your edit.  I like.

Answer (score 2):

If you **do not care about ordering**, you could use `HashSet`:

```rust
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn main() {
    let data = vec![1, 2, 2, 3, 2];
    let res: Vec<u32> = data
        .iter()
        .copied()
        .collect::<HashSet<_>>()
        .into_iter()
        .collect();
    println!("{:?}", res);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1e58ee2eb68c5700f65f02be12613f32)

Idea is going from Vec -> HashSet -> Vec again.

Comment: Chances are going back to a `Vec` isn't even needed – just keep the `HashSet`.

Comment: Note that this approach has an average runtime of O(n), while the `sort(); dedup();` approach is O(n log n).

Comment: @SvenMarnach, out of curiosity. what is the cost of dedup itself? I'm taking a look at the implementation https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/vec/mod.rs.html#1534
But it is not clear to me how it works exacly.

Comment: The dedup is O(n), but sorting is O(n log n). The implementation is complicated because the comparison function (or dropping elements) could panic, so it's hard to make sure that the vector is always in a defined state.

Comment: The deduping algorithm itself is simple. It keeps a read pointer and a write pointer, and only advances the write pointer when an element that doesn't belong to the same bucket is found. At the end, all elements after the write pointer are dropped.

Comment: @SvenMarnach, awesome. Nice and simple explanation, thanks a lot!!

Comment: @SvenMarnach that a odd statement, I argue is way more complicated. First it's ignore the cost of hashing function, secondly, `O(n)*~` is different than `O(n)`. Also you don't count the cost of new allocation.

Comment: @Stargateur The runtime of the hashing function is O(1). The amortized cost of reallocations while building the hash set is also O(1). None of these are "ignored" – they just don't change the amortized runtime of the algorithm in any way. I'm honestly not sure what exactly you find "odd" about what I said, and still believe everything I said is accurate. I could use Ω(n) instead of O(n), but I generally find that too much effort to type on a UK keyboard.

Comment: @SvenMarnach what I try to said it's that hashmap are NOT MAGIC and I tired of people continue to spread miss information about it. At least std clearly state it https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/#maps. One insert is `O(1)~*` but insert n object will for sure trigger reallocation and more, thus claiming it's simply `O(n)` is in practice completely false. And again that doesn't take in account hash function. Complexity is not easy and hashmap is not magic. I would prefer see benchmark to see different implementation with different parameter than just use an O notation here.

Comment: @Stargateur I still don't get your point. Filling a hash set with n values has an average time complexity of O(n) _including all reallocations_ because it's grown exponentially. Inserting an element in a hash map has an amortized complexity of O(1). This includes the hash function and possible reallocations. I agree that amortized analysis doesn't tell the full story in practice, and that high constant factors can easily be worse than a logarithmic complexity, but I didn't make any statements about that. I just stated the amortized complexity of the algorithms. No misinformation here.